# Dynamics365: How to convert binary image to actual image

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I'm working on an app using nodejs and ionic that communicate with Dynamics 365.

My problem is that I don't understand the return of the image.

According to [the contact EntityType documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/contact?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9)

> entityimage Edm. Binary Shows the default image for the record

Here's what returns the CRM for the image:

`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`

What is this format ? How can I convert it so I can display an image ?

**EDIT 1**

I have tried this way

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + btoa('your-binary-data');
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was

```
let img = "data:image/png;base64,"+ "binary-data";
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an example here for working with entity images [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn511697.aspx). It's C#, but the same basic principles apply.

> Retrieves the records with the entityimage attribute and saves the
>   resized files.

```
//Retrieve and download the binary images
string binaryImageQuery = String.Format(@"<fetch mapping='logical'>
    <entity name='{0}'>
    <attribute name='sample_name' />
    <attribute name='entityimage' />
    </entity>
</fetch>",_customEntityName.ToLower());

EntityCollection binaryImageResults = _serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(binaryImageQuery));

Console.WriteLine("Records retrieved and image files saved to: {0}", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
foreach (Entity record in binaryImageResults.Entities)
{
    String recordName = record["sample_name"] as String;
    String downloadedFileName = String.Format("Downloaded_{0}", recordName);
    byte[] imageBytes = record["entityimage"] as byte[];
    var fs = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(downloadedFileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));
    fs.Write(imageBytes);
    fs.Close();
    Console.WriteLine(downloadedFileName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but doesn't help me.Please look at the edit